# Improve Performance On GUI log

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface

Thanks to Yair Altman's excellent [post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/rich-contents-log-panel/#more-4180) on [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com), I've tried to implement a GUI logging program using a rich editbox and the underlying java components. Here is the simplified version of the code:

First the code to create the panel

```
function jEditbox = logPanel()
    hFig = figure('color', 'w');
    hPanel = uipanel(hFig);

    % Prepare the log editbox
    hLogPanel = uicontrol('style', 'edit', 'max', 5, 'Parent', hPanel, ...
        'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0, 0.2, 1, 0.8], 'Background', 'w');

    % Get the underlying Java editbox, which is contained within a scroll-panel
    jScrollPanel = findjobj(hLogPanel);
    try
        jScrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(jScrollPanel.java.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        jScrollPanel = jScrollPanel.getViewport();
    catch %#ok<CTCH>
        % may possibly already be the viewport, depending on release/platform etc.
    end
    jEditbox = handle(jScrollPanel.getView, 'CallbackProperties');

    % Prevent user editing in the log-panel
    jEditbox.setEditable(false);

    % Set-up a Matlab callback function to handle hyperlink clicks
    set(jEditbox,'HyperlinkUpdateCallback',@linkCallbackFcn);

    % Ensure we have an HTML-ready editbox
    HTMLclassname = 'javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit';
    if ~isa(jEditbox.getEditorKit, HTMLclassname)
        jEditbox.setContentType('text/html');
    end
end
```

Then the logging code:

```
function logMessage(jEditbox, text)
    % newText = [iconTxt, msgTxt ' '];
    text = [text '<br/>'];

    % Place the HTML message segment at the bottom of the editbox
    currentHTML = char(jEditbox.getText);
    newHTML = strrep(currentHTML, '</body>', text);
    jEditbox.setText(newHTML);
    endPosition = jEditbox.getDocument.getLength;
    jEditbox.setCaretPosition(endPosition);
end
```

I have two problems:

1. There are major performance issues in applications that will require a large number of logged messages (i.e. > 500). Using the profiler and the following code (note that I've modified `why` to return a string rather than printing to the command line), I've seen that the bottleneck is with `setText()`. Can anyone explain what the spikes in the graph are?

   ```
   h = logPanel();

   n = 1e3;
   time = nan(n, 1);
   profile on
   for i = 1:n
       tic
       logMessage(h, why)
       time(i) = toc;
   end
   profile viewer
   avgTime = mean(time);
   figure('color', 'w')
   bar(time)
   hold on
   plot([0, n], avgTime*ones(1, 2), '-k', 'LineWidth', 2)
   hold off
   title(sprintf('Average Time = %f [s]', avgTime));
   ```

   [image: benchmark]

   If I add a `pause(0.1)` after the `toc`, then the graph looks like

   [image: benchmark_pause]

   What's going on here?
2. This results in a very "flashy" log panel. Each time I write a message, the contents flicker as it scrolls to the top and then back to the bottom. Once again, this defect is due to `setText()`, which forces the caret to the beginning of the document.

I'm looking for solutions to either of these problems, preferrably both.

Comment: Average time is between 4 and 16 milliseconds on my OSX 10.8 and R2012b, without `pause(0.1)`

Comment: It seems that R2013b is less efficient in this department than R2012b. I tried this on 2012b and got similar results as you. Try runnning the benchmark with a larger `n` (eg, 5000). I'm still getting quite a large slowdown.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with `getText()` to be the bottleneck, but I would imaging that putting a `drawnow` after `toc` or before `tic` you would see a similar change.  If my intuition is right, then the discrepancy is because of an event queue (probably graphics objects) that gets flushed on one of the `jEditbox` methods (probably `getText`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, using `getText()`, `String` manipulation and `setText()` is a bottleneck. You force the editor component to convert it’s entire contents into an HTML representation and to reparse the entire HTML representation after the change. The editor is not able to detect that you just added a bit of text. The more contents your component has, the higher the performance loss.

If you have a Swing text component and want to append some text at the end you can use:

1. (the easy one) for plain text:

   ```
   textComp.setCaretPosition(textComp.getDocument().getLength());
   textComp.replaceSelection("\nMore Text");
   ```
2. (not so much harder) for text in the content type, e.g. HTML:

   ```
   Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
   textComp.getEditorKit().read(
     new StringReader("More <i>styled</i> text"), doc, doc.getLength());
   ```

In the second case, if you want to move the caret to the end you have to add the `setCaretPosition` invocation like in the first case.